# Uso y redireccionamiento con middleware laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buen dia, vengo usando laravel 5.6 y acabo de aplicar varios middleware a mi proyecto con la finalidad de proteger las rutas, en el acceso a los diferentes roles de usuario, pero al realizar el login me sigue redireccionando a 'home'.

Asi es como tengo los middleware declarados

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
'admin'=> \App\Http\Middleware\admin::class,
'almacen'=> \App\Http\Middleware\almacen::class,
'boletas'=> \App\Http\Middleware\boletas::class,
];
```

Donde a cada archivo middleware le coloque un switch, quedando de esta forma:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Closure;
use Session;


class almacen
{
/**
* Handle an incoming request.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @param  \Closure  $next
* @return mixed
*/
protected $auth;
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
 $this->auth=$auth;
}
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
switch ($this->auth->user()->id_role)
{
    case '1':
        return redirect()->to('admin');
        break;
    case '2':
        //return redirect()->to('almacen');
        break;
    case '3':
        return redirect()->to('boletas');
        break;

} 
return $next($request);
}
```

También modifique el archivo RedirectIfAuthenticated.php, quedando este asi:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
/**
* Handle an incoming request.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @param  \Closure  $next
* @param  string|null  $guard
* @return mixed
*/
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) 
{
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    switch ($this->auth->user()->id_role)
    {
        case '1':
            return redirect()->to('admin');
            break;
        case '2':
            return redirect()->to('almacen');
            break;
        case '3':
            return redirect()->to('boletas');
            break;
        default:
            return redirect()->to('login');
            break;
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
return $next($request); 

}
}
```

Si alguien por favor pudiera decirme en que estoy fallando o donde mas debo modificar la redirección después del login

Comment: te da un error al redireccionar o no redirecciona?

Comment: Me direcciona al 'home'

Comment: antes de ejecutar el if haz un dd así  `dd($this->auth->user()->id_role);` y al otro middleware para ver si te están llegando esos datos.

Comment: ¿son strings o números los valores en los case?

Comment: eso me preguntaba también, deberían ser enteros no string dado el tipo de dato , quiza.

Comment: Los valores son números ya que son id que corresponden a la tabla roles, al parecer no esta revisando los middleware ya que al poner dd($this->auth->user()->id_role);, no me respondio nada y me sigue direccionando al home

Comment: Y la ruta 'home' esta entrando a esos middleware???

Comment: No para nada no existe la vista para alguna ruta home